# How to get rid of i386 libs?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries

Yesterday, I tried to install the Ubuntu 64bit package for Netviewer. This package seems to be a big mess as it is not really a 64bit version of the app, but instead uses Wine to get it to run. Along with the install, it installed thousands :-) of i386 libs.

How do I get rid of them? More precisely, can I somehow see which libs were installed yesterday?

Comment: Are you running the 64 bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Sebi, remove these with caution. Despite having a 64bit machine the i386 libs are dependencies for many drivers and apps you might be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what each run of `apt` installed by looking at apt's log file, located at `/var/log/apt/history.log`. You can remove them by uninstalling whatever package caused them to be pulled in. You cannot remove them while keeping that package because these libs are needed to run it.